# Find dependent type libraries in typelib file through code

Tags: com

Looking for a way to find the dependent type libraries for a type library.  For example, when declaring a dependent library in IDL, a common dependency is stdole2.tlb and is declared as:

importlib("stdole2.tlb");

I can use OleView.exe to view these dependencies, but I am trying to figure out how to do it in code.  There doesn't appear to be any member in the ITypeLib or ITypeLib2 interfaces that can grab these dependencies.  I've scoured the OLE Automation reference and have not found a way to grab the interfaces.

Are they somehow in the binary resource format for the type library?

Anybody that can point me in the right direction?

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no master list of dependencies easily available from `ITypeLib`. Instead, one is supposed to enumerate all the types in the library, descending into interface methods and their parameters and such, and call `ITypeInfo::GetContainingTypeLib` on each. This may give you a different library than the one you started from (as determined by ITypeLib::GetLibAttr).

Comment: Joe, did my answer help you at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a complete implementation of a `GetDependencies` function for a type library.

This will return an [`unordered_set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/unordered-set-class) of `ITypeLibPtr` smart pointers. Note the hashing function, which enables these smart pointers to be used in [`unordered_set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/unordered-set-class) and other hashing containers.

This only returns the first-level dependencies. If those type libraries have additional dependencies, you can use this method in some recursive manner to get a complete set of dependencies (first-level and beyond).

Circular references (e.g. `IInterfaceA` has a property which returns an `IInterfaceB` pointer, and `IInterfaceB` has a property which returns an `IInterfaceA` pointer) are supported by storing an [`unordered_set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/unordered-set-class) of the visited `ITypeInfo`s while crawling through the type library.

This code is designed to throw [`_com_error`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/com-error-class) exceptions (in addition to any STL exceptions that may occur when working with the [`unordered_set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/unordered-set-class)). Handle these as appropriate. If you don't want to deal with [`_com_error`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/com-error-class) exceptions, replace the `_com_util::CheckError` calls with your own error-handling logic for `HRESULT` values.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <unordered_set>

// gets dependencies of a type library
std::unordered_set<ITypeLibPtr> GetDependencies(ITypeLib* pTypeLib);

// gathers dependencies of a type library
void GetDependenciesHelper(ITypeLib* pTypeLib, std::unordered_set<ITypeInfoPtr>* pHistory, std::unordered_set<ITypeLibPtr>* pOutput);

// gathers dependencies of a type
void GetDependenciesHelper(ITypeLib* pTypeLib, ITypeInfo* pTypeInfo, std::unordered_set<ITypeInfoPtr>* pHistory, std::unordered_set<ITypeLibPtr>* pOutput);

// gathers dependencies of a reference
void GetDependenciesHelper(ITypeLib* pTypeLib, ITypeInfo* pTypeInfo, HREFTYPE hRefType, std::unordered_set<ITypeInfoPtr>* pHistory, std::unordered_set<ITypeLibPtr>* pOutput);

// gathers dependencies of a reference
void GetDependenciesHelper(ITypeLib* pTypeLib, ITypeInfo* pTypeInfo, TYPEDESC& referencedTypeDescription, std::unordered_set<ITypeInfoPtr>* pHistory, std::unordered_set<ITypeLibPtr>* pOutput);

// gathers dependencies of a function declaration
void GetDependenciesHelper(ITypeLib* pTypeLib, ITypeInfo* pTypeInfo, FUNCDESC& functionDescription, std::unordered_set<ITypeInfoPtr>* pHistory, std::unordered_set<ITypeLibPtr>* pOutput);

// gathers dependencies of a variable declaration
void GetDependenciesHelper(ITypeLib* pTypeLib, ITypeInfo* pTypeInfo, VARDESC& variableDescription, std::unordered_set<ITypeInfoPtr>* pHistory, std::unordered_set<ITypeLibPtr>* pOutput);

// gathers dependencies of an array declaration
void GetDependenciesHelper(ITypeLib* pTypeLib, ITypeInfo* pTypeInfo, ARRAYDESC& arrayDescription, std::unordered_set<ITypeInfoPtr>* pHistory, std::unordered_set<ITypeLibPtr>* pOutput);

// gathers dependencies of an array element declaration
void GetDependenciesHelper(ITypeLib* pTypeLib, ITypeInfo* pTypeInfo, ELEMDESC& elementDescription, std::unordered_set<ITypeInfoPtr>* pHistory, std::unordered_set<ITypeLibPtr>* pOutput);

namespace std
{
    // provides a function for hashing ITypeLibPtr instances by their raw address
    template<> struct hash<ITypeLibPtr>
    {
        size_t operator()(ITypeLibPtr const& pTypeLib) const { return pTypeLib; }
    };
    // provides a function for hashing ITypeInfo instances by their raw address
    template<> struct hash<ITypeInfoPtr>
    {
        size_t operator()(ITypeInfoPtr const& pTypeInfo) const { return pTypeInfo; }
    };
}

std::unordered_set<ITypeLibPtr> GetDependencies(ITypeLib* pTypeLib)
{
    // get dependencies
    std::unordered_set<ITypeLibPtr> output;
    std::unordered_set<ITypeInfoPtr> history;
    GetDependenciesHelper(pTypeLib, &history, &output);
    return output;
}

void GetDependenciesHelper(ITypeLib* pTypeLib, std::unordered_set<ITypeInfoPtr>* pHistory, std::unordered_set<ITypeLibPtr>* pOutput)
{
    // iterate over type infos
    auto typeInfoCount = pTypeLib->GetTypeInfoCount();
    for (UINT typeInfoIndex = 0; typeInfoIndex < typeInfoCount; ++typeInfoIndex)
    {
        // get type info
        ITypeInfoPtr pTypeInfo;
        _com_util::CheckError(pTypeLib->GetTypeInfo(typeInfoIndex, &pTypeInfo));

        // get dependencies for type info
        GetDependenciesHelper(pTypeLib, pTypeInfo, pHistory, pOutput);
    }
}

void GetDependenciesHelper(ITypeLib* pTypeLib, ITypeInfo* pTypeInfo, std::unordered_set<ITypeInfoPtr>* pHistory, std::unordered_set<ITypeLibPtr>* pOutput)
{
    // short-circuit if we've already processed this type info
    if (!pHistory->insert(pTypeInfo).second)
        return;

    // get type attributes
    TYPEATTR* typeAttributes;
    _com_util::CheckError(pTypeInfo->GetTypeAttr(&typeAttributes));
    try
    {
        // special handling for aliases
        if (typeAttributes->typekind == TKIND_ALIAS)
        {
            // get dependencies of the alias
            GetDependenciesHelper(pTypeLib, pTypeInfo, typeAttributes->tdescAlias, pHistory, pOutput);
        }
        else
        {
            // iterate over implemented types
            auto implementedTypeCount = typeAttributes->cImplTypes;
            for (WORD implementedTypeIndex = 0; implementedTypeIndex < implementedTypeCount; ++implementedTypeIndex)
            {
                // get type reference
                HREFTYPE hRefType;
                _com_util::CheckError(pTypeInfo->GetRefTypeOfImplType(implementedTypeIndex, &hRefType));

                // get dependencies of the implementation
                GetDependenciesHelper(pTypeLib, pTypeInfo, hRefType, pHistory, pOutput);
            }

            // iterate over functions
            auto functionCount = typeAttributes->cFuncs;
            for (WORD functionIndex = 0; functionIndex < functionCount; ++functionIndex)
            {
                // get function description
                FUNCDESC* functionDescription;
                _com_util::CheckError(pTypeInfo->GetFuncDesc(functionIndex, &functionDescription));
                try
                {
                    // get dependencies of the function declaration
                    GetDependenciesHelper(pTypeLib, pTypeInfo, *functionDescription, pHistory, pOutput);
                }
                catch (...)
                {
                    // release function description
                    pTypeInfo->ReleaseFuncDesc(functionDescription);
                    throw;
                }

                // release function description
                pTypeInfo->ReleaseFuncDesc(functionDescription);
            }

            // iterate over variables
            auto variableCount = typeAttributes->cVars;
            for (WORD variableIndex = 0; variableIndex < variableCount; ++variableIndex)
            {
                // get variable description
                VARDESC* variableDescription;
                _com_util::CheckError(pTypeInfo->GetVarDesc(variableIndex, &variableDescription));
                try
                {
                    // get dependencies of the variable declaration
                    GetDependenciesHelper(pTypeLib, pTypeInfo, *variableDescription, pHistory, pOutput);
                }
                catch (...)
                {
                    // release variable description
                    pTypeInfo->ReleaseVarDesc(variableDescription);
                    throw;
                }

                // release variable description
                pTypeInfo->ReleaseVarDesc(variableDescription);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        // release type attributes
        pTypeInfo->ReleaseTypeAttr(typeAttributes);
        throw;
    }

    // release type attributes
    pTypeInfo->ReleaseTypeAttr(typeAttributes);
}

void GetDependenciesHelper(ITypeLib* pTypeLib, ITypeInfo* pTypeInfo, HREFTYPE hRefType, std::unordered_set<ITypeInfoPtr>* pHistory, std::unordered_set<ITypeLibPtr>* pOutput)
{
    // get referenced type info
    ITypeInfoPtr referencedTypeInfo;
    _com_util::CheckError(pTypeInfo->GetRefTypeInfo(hRefType, &referencedTypeInfo));

    // get referenced type lib
    ITypeLibPtr referencedTypeLibrary;
    UINT referencedTypeInfoIndex;
    _com_util::CheckError(referencedTypeInfo->GetContainingTypeLib(&referencedTypeLibrary, &referencedTypeInfoIndex));

    // store dependency
    if (referencedTypeLibrary != pTypeLib)
        pOutput->insert(referencedTypeLibrary);
}

void GetDependenciesHelper(ITypeLib* pTypeLib, ITypeInfo* pTypeInfo, TYPEDESC& referencedTypeDescription, std::unordered_set<ITypeInfoPtr>* pHistory, std::unordered_set<ITypeLibPtr>* pOutput)
{
    switch (referencedTypeDescription.vt)
    {
        case VT_PTR:
        {
            // get dependencies of the pointer declaration
            GetDependenciesHelper(pTypeLib, pTypeInfo, *referencedTypeDescription.lptdesc, pHistory, pOutput);
            break;
        }
        case VT_CARRAY:
        {
            // get dependencies of the array declaration
            GetDependenciesHelper(pTypeLib, pTypeInfo, *referencedTypeDescription.lpadesc, pHistory, pOutput);
            break;
        }
        case VT_USERDEFINED:
        {
            // get dependencies of the UDT reference
            GetDependenciesHelper(pTypeLib, pTypeInfo, referencedTypeDescription.hreftype, pHistory, pOutput);
            break;
        }
    }
}

void GetDependenciesHelper(ITypeLib* pTypeLib, ITypeInfo* pTypeInfo, FUNCDESC& functionDescription, std::unordered_set<ITypeInfoPtr>* pHistory, std::unordered_set<ITypeLibPtr>* pOutput)
{
    // get dependencies of the function return value
    GetDependenciesHelper(pTypeLib, pTypeInfo, functionDescription.elemdescFunc, pHistory, pOutput);

    // iterate over parameters
    auto parameterCount = functionDescription.cParams;
    for (SHORT parameterIndex = 0; parameterIndex < parameterCount; ++parameterIndex)
    {
        // get parameter description
        auto& parameterDescription = functionDescription.lprgelemdescParam[parameterIndex];

        // get dependencies of the parameter declaration
        GetDependenciesHelper(pTypeLib, pTypeInfo, parameterDescription, pHistory, pOutput);
    }
}

void GetDependenciesHelper(ITypeLib* pTypeLib, ITypeInfo* pTypeInfo, VARDESC& variableDescription, std::unordered_set<ITypeInfoPtr>* pHistory, std::unordered_set<ITypeLibPtr>* pOutput)
{
    // get dependencies of the variable declaration
    GetDependenciesHelper(pTypeLib, pTypeInfo, variableDescription.elemdescVar, pHistory, pOutput);
}

void GetDependenciesHelper(ITypeLib* pTypeLib, ITypeInfo* pTypeInfo, ARRAYDESC& arrayDescription, std::unordered_set<ITypeInfoPtr>* pHistory, std::unordered_set<ITypeLibPtr>* pOutput)
{
    // get dependencies of the array declaration
    GetDependenciesHelper(pTypeLib, pTypeInfo, arrayDescription.tdescElem, pHistory, pOutput);
}

void GetDependenciesHelper(ITypeLib* pTypeLib, ITypeInfo* pTypeInfo, ELEMDESC& elementDescription, std::unordered_set<ITypeInfoPtr>* pHistory, std::unordered_set<ITypeLibPtr>* pOutput)
{
    // get dependencies of the array element declaration
    GetDependenciesHelper(pTypeLib, pTypeInfo, elementDescription.tdesc, pHistory, pOutput);
}
```

Comment: `ITypeLib` and `ITypeInfo` are very detailed. If I've overlooked or misimplemented anything, please let me know so I can correct this code.

Comment: Happened to have same problem and noticed you never got marked as answer - thought you'd like to know that your solution did work pretty well for what I needed. Much appreciated!

Comment: Since the answer worked for another, I'll give it credit. I ended up doing something else--found some other way back in the day...with some undocumented structures that worked.